# Why is $\sum_{k=0}^6 {a_n}^{(k)} \varepsilon ^k = \sum_{x_1,x_2,\ldots ,x_n\in \{1,3,4,6,7,9\} } \varepsilon^{x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n} $?

Tags: combinatorics, complex-numbers, summation, contest-math

Why does $$\sum_{k=0}^6 {a_n}^{(k)} \varepsilon ^k = \sum_{x_1,x_2, ... ,x_n\in \{1,3,4,6,7,9\} } \varepsilon ^{x_1+x_2+...+x_n  }$$
where ${a_n}^{(k)}$ is the number of n-digit numbers, all of whose digits are $1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9$ and whose digit sum is congruent to $k \bmod 7$? Additionally $\varepsilon=\cos\frac{2\pi}{7}+i\sin\frac{2\pi}{7}$ , although I do not know if this even matters.

This algebraic manipulation is the "obvious" beginning of a proof in the book "Problems from the book" and I found many similar solutions of problems in this book and "Complex numbers from a to z".

I am not a college student and my mother tongue is not English, so please point out possible improvements. I am thankful for any answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to MSE. It suffices to observe that $ \epsilon^{k}  = \epsilon^{k \pmod7} $. Now consider $$ \left( \sum_{k=1}^7\epsilon^k\right)^n = \left(\sum_{x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n \in \{1,3,4,6,7,9\}}\epsilon^{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}\right)$$
To see its significance in counting observe that from each of the parantheses of the product  $$ \left( \sum_{k=1}^7\epsilon^k\right)^n $$ you are choosing a digit modulo seven so finally the coefficient of $\epsilon^k$ will be the number of $n$ digit numbers whose sum is $k$ modulo seven.  This completes the proof.